# LifecycleException error when deploying Spring Boot project on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I know there are old threads related to this issue but none of them are any help to me. I'm trying to deploy a spring boot project on remote Tomcat server but facing the error below.  JVM version 14.0.1 is same on compiler and server machines. I have tried the WAR file on my local tomcat it works.

Error

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/digivote] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/digivote]]]
```

Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DigivoteApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DigivoteApplication.class);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DigivoteApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
...

<name>digivote</name>
<description>DigiVote project for Spring Boot</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Comment: Verify your JDK version. Stop the tomcat and clean everything and ensure a helloWorld app is working to rule out any environment issues.

Comment: Done all the above, HelloWorld works wonders too but I'm still having same issue.

Comment: Can you attach the output of `logs/catalina.out` file? Also, your java version is 1.8 or 14? Try to use the same JRE version for tomcat too.

Comment: ... Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL executionGenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution ...

Comment: I haven't changed the application.properties where the database connection is

Comment: Your app is not able to connect to DB for DDL execution. Do you need to execute DDL at the startup? If not disable that or give the user correct privileges.

Comment: I've managed to sort out one problem but got into another, now I'm get this `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` I have not changed any of the database properties.